# Utilisation du mot « effectivement »

Tags: sens

Pourquoi, dans les média surtout, utilise-t-on le mot 'effectivement' une, deux, trois fois dans une intervention. Le mot signifie souvent que la personne est d'accord avec ce qui vient d'être dit, mais pas toujours. Que peut-on vouloir dire en l'insérant ici et là dans une phrase?

Comment: Tu devrais peut-être poser deux questions distinctes, elles n'ont pas l'air d'avoir de lien. (Et ne t'embête pas à signer, ton nom apparaît en en dessous le ta question à droite).

Comment: Dans quel cas "Effectivement" peut signifier qu'on est pas d'accord avec ce qui vient d'être dit ?

Comment: Dans le sens premier "Dans les faits". On exprimerait ensuite que "Dans le fond" (fondamentalement), l'interlocuteur a tord.

Comment: Cas concret : [cette réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/21968/7321)

Comment: @T.Nel : avoir tor**t**

Answer (score 5):

"Effectivement" permet de confirmer qu'une affirmation est vraie. Mais il ne faut pas oublier que ce mot possède un second sens, plus proche de son étymologie, qui est : "Dans les faits".

Un exemple pour le second sens est : 
"Bien qu'effectivement cela n'ait pas eu d'impact, cela aurait pu arriver".

Effectivement peut aussi être utilisé après sa propre affirmation. Pour reprendre un exemple de [ce site](http://www.la-definition.fr/definition/effectivement) : "Si la société compte effectivement plus de membres, la lutte est encore plus ardente". On aurait pu remplacer ici "effectivement" par "bien", dans le sens non-numéraire. Dans un autre contexte, cela aurait aussi pu signifier que l'interlocuteur aurait raison de se défendre en disant que la société compte plus de membre. Une forme d'anticipation donc.

Je pense donc que c'est cette forme d'anticipation qui a pu vous paraître erronée. On pourrait la considérer comme un abus de langage du fait du sens premier, qui a depuis évolué pour s'éloigner du sens étymologique mais est à présent accepté par l'Académie Française.

Comment: Est-ce que le 2d sens, celui de "Dans les faits," correspond un peu au 1er sens (dans mon *Le Robert-Micro*) de *actuellement* (= ‘Dans les circonstances actuelles’)? … J’en demande car cette discussion sur l’[ab]usage  de *effectivement* en français ressemble un peu à celle en anglais sur l’abus potentiel de notre version du mot *actuellement* (‘actually’) et je me demande, par curiosité,  s’il y a peut-être une connexion.    Merci et +1

Comment: @PapaPoule Actually se traduit par "en fait" en français, qui est aussi beaucoup utilisé à tout va. Je pense que le sens est proche, mais tout de même différent. au sens littéral, "En fait" veut dire qu'on contredit ce qui vient d'être dit (en corrigeant ensuite ce qui a été dit), alors que "Effectivement" confirme ce qui a été dit (en apportant ensuite des précisions supplémentaire). Ce sont en fait des mots de liaisons, pour indiquer qu'on va continuer à parler du même sujet que la personne qui lui a donné la parole...

Comment: "Actuellement" n'a pas du tout le sens de "Actually" (en France en tous cas, peut-être est-ce différent au Québec?).

Comment: @AnneAunyme Pas que je sache ; dans tous les cas le sens d'effectivement qu'avait [_actuellement_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/actuellement) au 14e est disparu, sauf en philo, au profit du sens courant. C'est l'histoire de _en acte_ pour en _action_ quand ces deux mots se concurrençaient, et en passant en anglais leur _actually_ est basé sur [_actual_](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=actual&allowed_in_frame=0) qui est basé sur l'ancien _actuel_ qui pouvait avoir cette valeur de type _effectivement_. Merci.