# Faut-il toujours dire le « en » dans « en avoir marre » ?

Tags: expressions, pronoms

Si je n'aime plus manger des pommes de terre, est-ce qu'il est correct de dire « j'en ai marre de pommes de terre » ou juste « j'ai marre de pommes de terre » ?
Si je mets le « en » ça me donne l'impression que je répète deux fois le « de ». Ou peut-être que ce n'est pas une expression si on omet le « en » ?

Comment: Please note that you should use «des» in «J'en ai marre des pommes de terre». «J'en ai marre de ...» would expect a verb after, eg: «J'en ai marre de manger des pommes de terre» or «J'en ai marre de lire ce livre»

Comment: Par ailleurs _c'est marre !_ existe.

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt: pas en France.

Comment: @AnneAunyme C'est au [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/marre/49603?q=marre#49507) ; le sujet du site n'est pas la langue telle qu'on la parle uniquement en France, c'est la langue française. Et on n'a pas _en_ avec marre dans un tel cas, mais c'est en interjection. Merci.

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt: si tu utilises des expressions régionales il vaut mieux préciser que c'en est, même si elles sont correctes. Cela dit je t'accorde ce point. "C'est marre !" n'est pas un régionalisme mais de l'argot du siècle dernier.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Je suis d'accord. Mais c'est que je ne peux pas savoir quand c'est au Larousse sans autre précision que _populaire_ par exemple. Je ne fais que jeter un coup d'oeil ds. 2-3 dictionnaires et parfois je laisse un commentaire là-dessus. Perso. je n'utilise aucune de ces expressions avec _marre_... Merci.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effectivement on dit « j'en ai marre de ... ». l'expression «j'ai marre» n’existe pas.
Indeed we say « j'en ai marre de ... ». The expression «j'ai marre» doesn't exist.

Comment: Mais pourquoi ? Que'est-ce que le « en » remplace-t-il ?

Comment: @BenKnoble *En* ne remplace rien dans les expressions idiomatiques comme *en avoir assez/marre*, *s'en aller*, *en vouloir*,  *s'en rester là*, *s'en faire*, *(ne pas) en finir*, etc.  (il y en a beaucoup). Grevisse dit que ce *en*  a une valeur très imprécise, vaguement pronominale, vaguement adverbiale.