# Quel est le rôle de « en » dans « c'en est fini de » ?

Tags: en

1. I read [this Wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-cen-est-fini-de-r%c3%b4le-de-en.1826451/) thread, but I still don't grasp "en"?  *en* still feels superfluous to me?

> A l'armée, c'en est fini des pigeons voyageurs, concurrencés par le courrier électronique.

2. Why not just write "c<s>'en</s> est fini des pigeons voyageurs"?

[Madore](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-cen-est-fini-de-r%C3%B4le-de-en.1826451/post-9122195) replied

> This is a rather formal and somewhat outdated expression.
>   EN means OF IT => it is over, we have finished with it
>   EN relates actually to "the fact that pigeons are used for transporting mail".

[ChampagneBrut](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-cen-est-fini-de-r%C3%B4le-de-en.1826451/post-9122227) replied

> That's right. EN = (that's the end) of it)

I'm asking about this syntax in general, not just that phrase. I'll quote three other books.

*Comment j'ai appris à lire* par Agnès Desarthe. [Google Books doesn't show the page number](https://books.google.com/books?id=uln0oI_suPQC&pg=PT19&dq=%22c%27en+est+fini%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWidmS5ubpAhVmlnIEHbU1CRQQ6AEIkAEwCg#v=onepage&q=%22c'en%20est%20fini%22&f=false).

> Au bout d'un mois, la remplaqante est remplacée par la titulaire. **C'en est fini de** 
>   Prévert. Fini en classe, mais pas fini pour moi. Chaque jour, j'ouvre *Paroles* et je lis. 
>   Au bout d'une semaine ou deux, je récite sans le vouloir. Je connais tout par Ctrur. Je 
>   n'en parle personne, qui le dirais-je ? N'aimant pas lire, je n'évoque jamais mes 
>   lectures.

*S'il est minuit en Europe* par Pierre Moscovici. [Google Books doesn't show the page number](https://books.google.com/books?id=rk1CDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT109&dq=%22c'en%20est%20fini%22&pg=PT109#v=onepage&q=%22c'en%20est%20fini%22&f=false).

> Dans cet agenda, bonne nouvelle : **c'en est fini** du secret bancaire en 
>   Europe qui protégeait les évadés fiscaux. C'est une bataille 
>   qu'aujourd'hui nous avons gagnée, que j'avais engagée lors de mes 
>   années Bercy, ä laquelle je m'étais consacré dés les débuts de mon 
>   mandat la Commission. Les bastions sont tombés un un : Suisse, 
>   Liechtenstein, San Marin, Monaco, Andorre, tous ont passé avec 
>   I 'Union des accords d'échange automatique d'informations sur les 
>   comptes individuels. **C'en est fini de** l'échange la demande, qui 
>   permettait une administration nationale ou une banque de répondre 
>   ou de s'en dispenser, de répondre Vite ou lentement, complétement ou 
>   partiellement.

*L'objet et ses doubles: une relecture de Fitzgerald*
par Pascale Antolin-Pirès. [p 127.](https://books.google.com/books?id=3PILy6xeKCgC&pg=PA127&dq=%22c%27en+est+fini%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWidmS5ubpAhVmlnIEHbU1CRQQ6AEIaDAG#v=onepage&q=%22c'en%20est%20fini%22&f=false)

> d'une promenade, un moment plus tard en embrassant la main gantée de 
>   Dick (p. 231). Au contraire, lorsque le désir est enfin assouvi, l'objet du 
>   désir disparait et **c'en est fini de la** relation : « She wanted to be taken and 
>   she was » (p. 233). **C'en est fini aussi de la** fiction, comme en témoignent 
>   tant le dépouillement de la phrase que son univocité. Dans ces 
>   conditions, l'ambiguité du désir qu'exprime l'objet relationnel reflete 
>   l'ambigufté du sens, la mutabilité sémantiqueS7.
>         L'objet relationnel fait donc partie intégrante du proces narratif: il 
>   fonde l'architecture textuelle Sur un systeme, sinon d'objets leitmotive 
>   Cornme dans *Gatsby*, du moins de reflets et d'échos, aussi bien dans les 
>   scenes de violence que dans les scenes de séduction. En réalité, c'est 
>   avant tout d'un mouvement dialectique qu'il s'agit, de construction du 
>   sens d'une part, par cet effet de parallélisme et de répétition, mais aussi 
>   de déconstruction de celui-ci, par le recours tant i la parodie qu'i 
>   l'équivoque. Le lecteur n'est donc plus le consommateur d'un sens 
>   donné, il est « producteur »ss d'un sens interpreter, au sens musical de 
>   ce terme. Autrement dit, si l'objet relationnel expose la délitescence du 
>   tissu social, il dévoile aussi la trame complexe d'un texte multivoque 
>   jouant de tous les artifices, et indique ainsi le désir de l'auteur de voir le 
>   langage se libérer du carcan de l'imitation.

Comment: The same phenomenon has been discussed for *en avoir marre de*: see eg https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21967/faut-il-toujours-dire-le-en-dans-en-avoir-marre

Answer (score 4):

1. You should consider "***c'en est***/était/sera/serait... **fini de** sth" as a single unit, a set phrase. ***En*** has no explicit *antécédent* here like with the expressions ***en*** finir avec sth, *s'**en** aller*...
2. You can't. *<s>C'est fini des pigeons voyageurs</s>* is not grammatical although you might write:

   > *C'est fini, les pigeons voyageurs.*

   or better:

   > *Les pigeons voyageurs, c'est fini.*

Answer (score 1):

An added thought to the above...  If you compare "c'en est fini" to "c'est fini" the first one is basically indicating an entity (the practice of using carrier pigeons) that is being ended.  It can be used to add more emphasis to the whole of what is being considered finished/over in a sentence than just "c'est fini" (tho "c'est fini" with an exclamation point can certainly do that too).  The "en"  is talking about the end of the whole practice of using carrier pigeons.